# Saving as SVG in illustrator gives me an error

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm getting an error when I view my illustrator doc.

> error on line 33308 at column 20: Namespace prefix inkscape for
>   connector-curvature on path is not defined

My illustrator document is pretty basic except it uses a custom font. I don't know how to begin to solve this error. Any troubleshooting tips/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in Inkscape
(free at http://www.inkscape.org/en/download/ )

Go to <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Save As</kbd>

for <kbd>Save As Type</kbd> choose **Plain SVG**

This will remove all the references to inkscape namespace